# Variable might have not been initialized?

Tags: java

Here is my java code (a terrible brute force algorithm I know and that's the requirement). I think I have initialized the `j` variable in the for loop before any references, however when I run the compiler alerts.

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Brute {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filename = "./collinear/input" + args[0] + ".txt";
        In f = new In(filename);
        int N = f.readInt();
        Point[] points = new Point[N];
        int x, y;

        StdDraw.setScale(-10000, 50000);

        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            x = f.readInt();
            y = f.readInt();
            points[i] = new Point(x, y);
            points[i].draw();
        }

        Arrays.sort(points);


        int i, j, k, l;

        for(i = 0; i < N; i++)
            for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
                if(points[j] == points[i]) continue;
                for(k = 0; k < N; k++)
                    if((points[k] == points[i]) || (points[k] == points[j])) continue;
                    for(l = 0; l < N; l++) {
                        if((points[l] == points[i]) || (points[l] == points[j])
                            || (points[l] == points[k])) continue;
                        if(points[i].slopeTo(points[j]) == points[i].slopeTo(points[k])
                        && points[i].slopeTo(points[k]) == points[i].slopeTo(points[l])) {
                            StdOut.println(points[i].toString() 
                            + " -> " + points[j].toString() 
                            + " -> " + points[k].toString() 
                            + " -> " + points[l].toString());

                            points[i].drawTo(points[l]);
                        }
                    }       

    }
}
```

> Brute.java:31: error: variable j might not have been initialized
>
> `if((points[k] == points[i]) || (points[k] == points[j])) continue;`
>
> Brute.java:33: error: variable j might not have been initialized
>
> `if((points[l] == points[i]) || (points[l] == points[j])`

Comment: Quite a silly mistake of braces.

Comment: Doesn't your IDE warn you about suspicious indentations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put braces around the body of your for loops.

This:

```
for(j = 0; j < N; j++)
    if(points[j] == points[i]) continue;
    for(k = 0; k < N; k++) .....
```

is a for loop of one line that doesn't do anything, followed by another for loop.

You mean this:

```
for(j = 0; j < N; j++) {
    if(points[j] == points[i]) continue;
    for(k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        .....
    }
}
```

Comment: See kids, this is what happens when you try to be cute and clever and use new coding 'shortcuts' you've learned.

Comment: They can come in handy, but not always. Honestly, if curly bracers are such hell for you to use even on a one liner just put in next to the text. That's how I do it with some of my variables if I quickly set up the same object with different requirements.